# Sitecore Change Display name of Language

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to change the display name of a language version dropdown so that it makes content authors life easy.

[image]

Here I have two language versions *English* and *English (United Kingdom).* 
Is  there a way I can change the display name of that from ***English***  - to let's say 
**English(Rest of the World)**. 
I don't want to create a custom language or culture. Existing language and its culture are fine.  Just want to change the display name to make it easy for content authors to understand. 
Sitecore Version 8

Answer (score 0):

It use the build in .NET CultureInfo. Previous there was a Custom Language Registration tool on the Marketplace. To make a Custom language. but sound not a good idea for your issue. [Sitecore Marketplace](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/C/Custom_Language_Registration.aspx?sc_lang=en)

So create your own custom Language selector, Take a look at  this Article:
http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2015/08/display-flag-icon-in-language-dropdown.html

It tell you about the sitecore\shell\Override\Applications\Content Manager\Galleries\Languages\Gallery Languages.xml Customize this and place your version in the \sitecore\shell\Override\Applications\Content Manager\Galleries\Languages\ For your change you can decompile the code (with JetBrains dotPeek) and create your custom version of it.

Comment: Thanks @jbluemink. I dont want to create a custom language as i really want to use the En-us only. I just wanted to change the display.  I dont see much options. i would just stick with that naming for now